# TestFlight download link returning HTTP error 404?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, testflight

I opened the link https://developer.apple.com/testflight/, and then clicked on the **Download** button. It shows me HTTP error 404.

The link returning the HTTP error 404 is:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8

[image]

Can anyone please let me know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link is working for me so either your network is not routing enough traffic correctly to the server or the farm of servers Apple operates to run the store has one endpoint that's failing or down.

If you try again in 30 minutes or try from a different network (LTE / different carrier / different WiFi network) that might help you isolate if the network error is close to your device.

You also would want to do the usual things to rule out software or run time corruption on your iOS device. Restart the device - test other store links - sign out and back in to your App Store on a known good network.

In the end - you'd contact Apple online store support after you're sure it's not your device.

Comment: It's working now. I have no ideas what's wrong before...

Comment: sounds like a network error out of your control. Glad you're back in business @sgon00